# PHP/MySQL queries not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I have these tables in my database

[table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyNQF.png) named 'store_item_stock'

[table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ5fK.png) named 'store_item_color'

I am using the following code to create a dropdown of the item names and their respective codes:

```
//get colors
$get_colors_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT color_id FROM store_item_stock WHERE item_id = '" . $_GET["item_id"] . "' ORDER BY color_id";
$get_colors_res = $conn->query($get_colors_sql) or die("Couldn't connect :" . $conn->error);


$colors = $get_colors_res->fetch_array();
//if the item has colors
if ($get_colors_res->num_rows > 0 && !is_null($colors['color_id'])) {
    //create select statement
    $display_block .= "<p><strong>Available colors:</strong><br/>
   <select name=\"sel_item_color\">";

    do {
        $item_color = $colors['color_id'];
        //query the name belonging to that id
        $get_item_color_name_sql = "SELECT * FROM store_item_color WHERE color_id = ".$item_color;

        $get_item_color_name_res = $conn->query($get_colors_sql) or die("Couldn't connect :" . $conn->error);
        $color_name = $get_item_color_name_res->fetch_array();
        echo $color_name['color_id'];

        $display_block .= "<option value=\"" . $item_color . "\">" . $color_name['item_color'] . "</option>";

        echo "<pre>".var_dump($color_name)."</pre>";
    }while ($colors = $get_colors_res->fetch_array());
}

$display_block .= "</select>";

//free result
$get_colors_res->free();
$get_item_color_name_res->free();
```

However when I run this code, yet the select contains [3 empty strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpOr1.png).
I've tried var dumping and get this:

> 1array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["color_id"]=> string(1) "1" }
>
> 1array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["color_id"]=> string(1) "1" }
>
> 1array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["color_id"]=> string(1) "1" }

What can I do to fix this and have the name of the color show up in dropdown.

Comment: What's the name of table 1 and table 2?

Comment: table 1 is named 'store_item_stock'

table 2 is named 'store_item_color'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your var_dump `$color_name` doesn't contain an index which is `item_color`. Hence the empty selects.

I think you have the wrong query in the `do` loop, it should be

```
$get_item_color_name_res = $conn->query($get_item_color_name_sql) or die("Couldn't connect :" . $conn->error);
```